# Does it matter how many flags I retract?

Tags: support, retracted-flags

I find myself retracting a lot of flags when they're not approved quickly, because I sometimes am not 100% sure if I flagged them correctly. I'm usually sure the post is off-topic, but I am not sure for example if I should have flagged it as opinion based or too broad. I was just wondering if the number of retracted flags goes against me in any way.

Comment: *...when they're not approved quickly...* Isn't the queue for closure flags in the thousands? In any case, it doesn't count against you if your flag ages away and it takes days for that to happen.

Comment: How do you retract flags?

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms Try to flag a post you already flagged. You’ll then see an option to retract the flag.

Comment: If you're not sure you've flagged something correctly, why are you flagging at all? On the off-chance the flag slips through without proper scrutiny?

Comment: Close flags just age away most of the time anyway.

Comment: @BSMP, so any flags other than `ages away flags` might go against the flag caster?

Comment: @VinhVO Declined flags count against you with a certain percentage in a certain amount of time triggering a flagging ban

Comment: Further to what @BSMP said, three are currently [over 42,000 flags in the queue](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/835822/pending-flags-by-date), averaging **12.4 days old**, but some from as far back as February.  That's just one out of [eight review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Flags for closure aren't even seen by moderators, so no, that's not going to be a problem.

About the only real exception I could possibly imagine was if you were abusively casting flags (i.e. with inappropriate content in the flag text) and then trying to retract them a bit later in the hopes of avoiding consequences, or some other form of intentionally malicious behavior.  If you're flagging sincerely, you don't have to be worried about later retracting a flag you feel is no longer merited.

Additionally I wouldn't worry *too* much about which close reason is used in situations like that.  There is a decent amount of overlap between a lot of close reasons, and often more than one will apply.  It *is* worth taking a moment to consider which you think applies *most*, and which will have a message that will best help the OP figure out what they need to fix, but having the question closed with a less applicable-but-still-valid close reason is still far preferable to the question not being closed at all, so I wouldn't retract a flag over something like this.  Save retractions for either situations where the problem has been resolved since you flagged, or it very clearly was an error and doesn't require action.

Comment: In support of your *more than one [close reason] will apply*, see this [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/834282)

Comment: Might it be worth considering making close reason check boxes rather than exclusive radio buttons then?

Comment: @JamesHughes What would you get out of doing that?

Comment: @Servy if multiple close reasons apply they can all be ticked, would at the very least help the statistics be more useful

Comment: @JamesHughes And how would that be helpful?

Comment: It would only be helpful if several close-reasons were shown in that little box on closed questions, there might be several disjunct reasons why a post is off topic and the OP could potentially benefit from being made aware of all of them. Apart from that, I see no benefit, really. I don't think we need checkboxi.

Comment: > About the only real exception I could possibly imagine was if you were abusively casting flags (i.e. with inappropriate content in the flag text) and then trying to retract them a bit later in the hopes of avoiding consequences

Then why even flag them in the first place if you don't want the moderators to see?

Answer (score 4):

I just want to add a little bit behind [Servy's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365519/50049), which is a great answer.

## As a general rule ...

#### If:

- The UI allows you to do it without reverting to shenanigans like playing with the request / routes
- You are honestly acting in *good faith* (as in, it's not in any way your intent to cause any harm, game the system, harass anyone, etc)
- You *immediately* stop whatever you're doing if you notice that there *are* unintended consequences to whatever you're doing, or if a moderator asks you to stop

... then you probably don't have to worry about anyone having an unpleasant conversation with you about your use of the site. That goes for pretty much everything, and it needs to — the higher you get on the privilege scale, the more we rely on folks having good judgement to guide them if in doubt.

So in this particular case, no, there's nothing really wrong with it, *but* you obviously thought it seemed odd enough to warrant asking about it, so that same common sense should be telling you to just be careful. And, well, that's really all you have to do.

So in simpler terms, we're not going to get upset if it was obvious you were acting in good faith; a modicum of common sense goes a long way toward ensuring that's an easy assumption to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it matter how many flags I retract?

As far as I am aware there are no set-in-stone rules. "If I retract/flag X posts that will result in an automatic ban", no you do not, but it is possible it does matter in the end, and do not be surprised if you find someone tries to find out *why* you flagged them in the first place.

The question is why did you flag those posts?

1. Did they have an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or the "plz code free for me" type questions?
2. Were they in English/was the question/answer understandable/Did it actually answer the question?
3. Flagged because you dislike the user because of previous experience with them?
4. Just trying out some flags?
5. Not having enough experience to use them effectively?

While 5 is OK, "off topic" questions are sometimes quite hard to distinguish and you are still learning, you should still try and limit the wrong flags you do, that way retracting them will not be necessary, you will be armed with experience and will know what you are doing.   You could also get advice by asking on Meta, some users in chat may also advise you.  If you are seen multiple times on the review queue and you were wrong to flag (they may not notice that you have retracted your flag) someone might comment to try and help.

Eventually if you do keep misusing flags, then you retract them, and they have already been reviewed, you could get a ban and especially in the case of 3 and 4 (and by no means am I accusing you of any wrongdoing, this is just a few situations that may be the cause  of the problem).  You would in any case get at least a warning.

If you were correct in flagging and then retracted you flag, it is possible someone goes behind you and flags it again (or someone with a gold badge closes the post themselves), otherwise the flag just gets left until there are enough votes to accept or reject it.

In the end as long as you were not flagging through spite (or for revenge), other reasons and you are just making mistakes/uncertainty while learning (or you realise your mistake later), then you should not encounter any problems.  Learn how to use them and if in doubt ask or don't flag, someone with more experience is likely to anyway or the down-votes will just get the post deleted.

Not accepted quickly is not a good way to do things.  Many questions are closed through a users personal experience on the subject/how much they have been reviewing, they may not even know about the topic in which case they may skip it completely or take time to decide. There may also be a lack of reviewers. If your flag was unfounded it **will** get rejected, and if not it will get reopened later.  Ultimately retracting or leaving your flag just wastes the reviewers time (if unfounded) and so you should focus on getting your flags right.